# Styling html5 navigation bar

Tags: html, css, nav

I would like to style up my navigation bar, so it would look like this one [nav bar](http://pasteboard.co/V5I9d9A.png) on the picture. I have already startet and on the jsfiddle link below you are able to see what I have so far and as you can also see, that there are still a couple of things to fix.

It is important for me to align all elements to the same line, because I will maybe add some more elements to it (e.g. input field and button)

I would also like to have a background in two colors like on the picture. Lets say 30% purple, 70% black.

I have chosen T-Mobile logo image on purpose, because it is originaly very big. I have succeded to resize and fit it to the nav, however I would also like to ask if this is the right/best thing to do.

Thx in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/amsalk/y6km93gm/

```css
body {
     background: #EEE;
}

div#wrapper{
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
    width: 800px;
    height:2000px;
}

#horizNav {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background: black;
}

img {
    max-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h3 {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav id="horizNav">
            <img id="pageLogo" src="http://intranet.t-mobile.at/intranet/arbeitsplatz/T_Logo_magenta_schwarz_Brandneu_RGB.jpg" />
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </nav> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not writing whole html and css for you but follow these examples

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/